# Styling mode-line: how to remove border?

Tags: emacs, customization

I've been trying in vain to come up with a style that would remove the border around the mode-line, but no go... the face looks like this:

```
(mode-line-inactive ((,class
  (:box (:line-width <??> :style none)
   :background ,tron-berlin-darkest :foreground ,tron-gray-light))))
```

The values it would accept are 1..N and -1..-N, where N is some large number, but 0 or `nil` aren't accepted. And it will draw the line for some reason... Any idea how to get rid of that? Or, if that's for some reason is not possible, how to paint the line some other color?

BTW, if I don't specify any value, the default is 1... very useful :/

Also, if I don't specify the `:box`, the box is created by default :(

**EDIT**

Sorry, never mind, had to put `:box nil` - this cancels the box and the line around it.

Answer (score 5):

Had to to add to the face `:box nil` to override the default box settings.